# Series sum according to the formula C++

Tags: c++, sum, series

I need to write a program/function which calculates the series sum according to the formula:

[series sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idi9Q.jpg)

The data that the user types is: **m**.

I am a total beginner and I have no idea how to do it... I am assuming that I need to create a loop (or 2)... but how...? So I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol Σ (sigma) is generally used to denote a sum of multiple terms. In that way you have to sum all (1+j) / (2*j**3 + 3) for every j from 0 to m.

**As you see bellow, m is equal to 14, but you can change this parameter.**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float s = 0;
    int m = 14;
    for(int j = 0; j <= m; j++) s += (1 + j) / (pow(j, 3) + 3);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

**And if you need to take a user input you are welcome as well**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float s = 0;
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    for(int j = 0; j <= m; j++) s += (1 + j) / (pow(j, 3) + 3);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

**Using multiplication instead of pow function**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float s = 0;
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    for(int j = 0; j <= m; j++) s += (float)(1 + j) / (j*j*j + 3);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `(j * j * j)` instead of `pow(j, 3)`.  Usually multiplication is faster and more accurate than the call to `pow`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews added as a third variant down below.

Comment: Ahhh ok! Cause at the beginning I was really confused.. I was looking for some different formulas to calculate this but nothing worked.
I studied carefully the code you wrote. I got this now! Thank so sooo much!

Comment: @user15374677 If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept this answer.